# Extract pandas index with binary numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


binArray = np.array([[1, 0, 1]])
print(binArray)
list = ('Text0', 'Text1', 'Text2')
indx = pd.Index(list)
print(indx)
```

Hi !

How do I extract 'Text0' and 'Text2' with the help of binArray variable? Please note that both binArray & indx will always be of length N in my code.

Thank you!

Comment: Would this `[x for i, x in enumerate(list) if binArray[0][i]]` work for you? Also are you sure binArray is `[[]]` and not `[]`?

Comment: It works when using 'list' but I want to use the pandas index: 'indx', what then? Thank you!

Comment: `[indx[i] for i in range(len(indx)) if binArray[0][i]]` might be an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility is to use `np.where()` and `np.take()` to perform the required operation.

```
binArray = np.array([[1, 0, 1]])  # Are you sure its not [] instead of [[]]
list = ('Text0', 'Text1', 'Text2')
indx = pd.Index(list)

# get indices for all 1 in binArray[0]
indices = np.where(binArray[0]==1)[0]
result = np.take(indx, indices)
```

Your result is now `Index([u'Text0', u'Text2'], dtype='object')` which is what you require.

#### Explanation

[`np.take()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) takes the the array and indices as arguments and returns the values corresponding to the indices from the array. For example:

```
>>> a = [4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8]
>>> indices = [0, 1, 4]
>>> np.take(a, indices)
array([4, 3, 6])
```

[`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) returns elements from a given array based on a given condition. In this case, we're requesting for all the indices from `binArray[0]` where the value is `1` whose corresponding map in `indx` is what you need as the final result.

Comment: Thank you! This seems like a good solution & thanks for the explanation!